# Assigning a session variable into DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, session, detailsview

I have a Session Variable declared and checked that it exists. I would like the DetailsView to display the Session Variable number in the INSERT Textbox in the DetailsView. When the Insert Button is pressed I, require the record in the DetailsView to be despatched to the database, to create an additional record.
From the experimentation I have carried out, it appears to be difficult to penetrate the DetailsView. I imagine that there is a requirement for some "Code Behind" to be included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the detailsview `Databound` event and assign the value to the textbox. e.g.

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
 {
    TextBox TextBox1 = DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
    TextBox1.Text = Session["Name"].ToString();
 }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I have place your proposed code in my "Code Behind" on a separate wtout success.

Comment: I am uncertain whether this iis do-able. Unfortunately I am new to ASP.Net. I am not clear how I can get the code behind to synchronise with the Source.

Comment: When I added the code behind, I had the underlined errors.  
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
 if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert) 
 { 
    TextBox TextBox1 = DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox; 
    TextBox1.Text = Session["ID"].ToString(); 
 } 

}